# How can I hide special attributes in excel Slicer from a dimension in excel?

Tags: excel, dimension, slicers

I have a dimension with 5 member. I dont want to show all members that have information in fact in excel slicer from a dimension. need to hide some attributs. but how?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I find solution. You can add a new Boolean attribute in dimension and make it true or false. Then add new excel slicer in another sheet and connect it to your pivot (table/chart) and select only true value.

This cause all cube will be unprocessed. But you rich your solution. Another slicer will be filtered based on Boolean slicer